# Symfony 2 routing 2 similar routes but another controllers

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have problem with routing.
I created Route for my pages like that

`@Route("/{slug}", name="cms_site")`

I have another route to my admin dashboard like

```
@Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard_homepage")
```

Now when I try to open /dashboard I cant because symfony use "cms_site" controller.

How can I define that 
"dashboard_homepage" /dashboard is important that cms_site ?

Answer (score 0):

The routes in symfony2 are looked for in descending order. So, the first route matching the pattern is selected.

The placeholder routes like /{slug} must be at end of your routing definition. If you change the order of the actions or the order how you import the routing in routing.yml, should work.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @pabgaran answer,
if you are stuck in a way you can't change the order,
you can force the {slug} not to be dashboard with requirements and a regex :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slug}", requirements={"slug" = "^(?!.*(dashboard)).*$"} , name="cms_site")
 */
```

note : I haven't tested the regex in this particular case. It may needs to be adapted.